# HTTP Connections while iOS app is in background and retrying if offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I've written a basic location tracking app that will run in the background. (Not just a background thread, but when the device is dark.) I have the UIBackgroundModes key set and this part is working nicely writing locations to the screen.

Next, I need to process those locations. Based on location and some other criteria, the app will need to occasionally send some information to a server via HTTP get or post. There are a few challenges:

1. The messages need to be sent to the server even if the app is in the background.
2. The messages need to be sent to the server even if the device is offline when the message is generated (users will often be out of cell range while getting a gps location). The messages don't have to be sent immediately, of course, but they should be stored and sent when the device is back online.
3. If the message does not make it the first try, it should be resent  a few times before giving up.

I'm looking for help planning how to handle these three things.

The app will target iOS6+.

I'm a new iOS developer but I've developed a very similar app for android. I'm looking for general advice and strategies - not code unless there happens to be some out there already. I just don't know iOS / Objective C well enough yet to know if there are already classes or frameworks to handle this or help with aspects of it. I've seen plenty of "How to send data to a server" examples, that's not what I'm looking for. Instead, I'd like pointers to which classes or systems might help manage retrying connections/commands, how to handle this in the background, and so on. Also, warnings for issues to watch out for is helpful too. Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: have you resolved this?  new features in iOS 7 will allow some background processing and better implementation than 6

Answer (score 2):

You're going to quickly find that you are a lot more restricted in what you can and can't do while the app is in the background. Your best resource will be the [App States and Multitasking Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) in the iOS developer library. From the docs:

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
>   request specific permissions to run them in the background without
>   their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
>   run in the background:
>
> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
>     such as a music player app
> - Apps that keep users informed of their
>     location at all times, such as a navigation app
> - Apps that support
>     Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> - Newsstand apps that need to
>     download and process new content
> - Apps that receive regular updates
>     from external accessories
>
> Apps that implement these services must
>   declare the services they support and use system frameworks to
>   implement the relevant aspects of those services. Declaring the
>   services lets the system know which services you use, but in some
>   cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent your
>   application from being suspended.

Sounds like your app may qualify under the location bullet item. You can enable background location services by including the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your info.plist file, and you'll have to design the app to work well with background modes and background fetches (callbacks the system will provide, handled in your app delegate). Read up on "Tracking the User’s Location" section of the multitasking guide.

Also, there are some new considerations in iOS 7 to look into. If you have access to the member center, I recommend you check out the WWDC videos for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I have the location tracking working in the background, and am confident that it qualifies. I'm handling the CLLocationManagerDelegate calls in the background successfully (though it's taken me a while to get there). Now I'm trying to figure out how to do this HTTP stuff and how much queueing, retrying, and so on is already built into iOS and how much of it will work in the background.

Comment: Definitely look into NSOperationQueue. Ray Wenderlich has a solid tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Answer (score 2):

> I have the UIBackgroundModes key set and this part is working nicely writing locations to the screen.

As you are already using background modes, so the GPS functionality is hopefully working fine.

> The messages need to be sent to the server even if the app is in the background.

The app gets about 10 minutes of Background running time and then it is forcibly suspended by iOS.

```
//Check if device supports multi-tasking
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { 
        //Get the shared application instance
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; 
        //Create a task object
        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; 
        background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
            //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
            [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; 
            //Set the task to be invalid
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; 
            //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
        }];
        //Background tasks require you to use asynchronous tasks
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            //Perform your tasks that your application requires
            NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!, here we can send the request to server for 10 minutes.");
            //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
            [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; 
            //Invalidate the background_task
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; 
        });
    }
```

> The messages need to be sent to the server even if the device is
>   offline when the message is generated (users will often be out of cell
>   range while getting a gps location). The messages don't have to be
>   sent immediately, of course, but they should be stored and sent when
>   the device is back online.

For this functionality, create a HTTP Singleton class, and check if the internet is available or not. Also activate the internet change notification, so that, if the app gets internet connection during usage, the app can upload records on server. 
For uploading records on server, either you can create your own NSURLConnections in GCD for multiple connection support, or can use [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) third party open source library.

Comment: Does the app get 10 minutes of background run time each time a new location is provided, or just when the app first goes into the background?

Comment: it is provided everytime, whenever app is moving in background (multitasking)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should define background mode in your project, in order to perform background operations.

[Read this quick tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

If you already made this step, then you could just add some code to your locationManager's callback method. If you want to send data, then add some lines to perform request to server. You should avoid performing requests to often.

If request fails, you could store data in array or some kind of queue. Each time you will perform sending operation you could try to send whole saved data.

Comment: Thank you. Does iOS/Obj C have any built in queueing that you would recommend, or would I need to write that from scratch?

Comment: I don't know any good built in solution for that situation. I would do it from scratch, because it should be quite easy.